# Too many functions in java class, how to split in multiple files

Tags: java

I have a java class, which has lots of functions, and all are in one file. The total number of lines in this file is around 50K. I makes it very hard to read. Can I move some of the functions to different file? If yes, how to do that. And if no, is there is some other technique to make program more readable.

Comment: yes you can very well move some of the functions to different file. Ex - go through your file again and see if there is some piece of code(database call, any formatting etc) that you are using repetitively, those things you can refractor & put in a separate file like Utility.java etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refactor everything carefully with a lot of tests so you don't break anything. Surely you can extract some functions to a different class.

50K lines in one file is a lot. Use composition to extract a certain subset of instructions (adhere to [the Single Responsibility Principle!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)) into a separate class and simply keep a field that points to an instance of this class.

If you're asking if you can just split the same class over multiple files (like C#'s `partial`): no, you can't.

Answer (score 2):

Define domain objects (e.g. value objects) for the various concepts in your model,
and put functionality related to those classes inside them.

For instance if you have

```
public class MyBigClass {
   ...
   private String account;
   ...
   private boolean accountIsValid() { ... }
   ...
}
```

then separate the account into an Account class, like this:

```
public class Account {
  public Account(String accountNumber) { ... }
  public boolean isValid() { ... }
}

public class MyBigClass
  ...
  private Account account;
  ...
}
```

if you keep doing that, and you make sure functionality is always located together with
the value, your huge class will shrink rapidly. Try to avoid using native types (like String) for anything but the internal values of your value objects.

Also, look at libraries like commons-lang and google guava, to make sure you are not re-implementing something complex that there already exists a suitable solution for; Examples of classes that will both simplify your code and reduce the chance of implementation errors are EqualsBuilder and HashCodeBuilder.

To further improve your coding style, consider reading the following books:

- [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) by Robert C Martin
- [Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) by Erik Evans (note: this is a heavy, but
  important, read)
- [Applying UML and Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131489062) by Craig Larman